# Transposing a multi index data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe:

```py
data = {
  'A': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  'B': list('ABCABCD'),
  'C': range(12, 19)
}
pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['A', 'B'])

      C
A B    
0 A  12
  B  13
  C  14
1 A  15
  B  16
  C  17
  D  18
```

I need to convert this dataframe to

```py
   0    1
A  12   15
B  13   16
C  14   17
D  NaN  18
```

Context: I am doing a groupby operation, and the `apply` function is return a series. `groupby` then converts that to a multi index, but it is easiest for me to represent my data with group labels as columns instead of rows.

Comment: `df['C'].unstack('A')`, or `df.rename_axis([None, None])['C'].unstack(0)` for the exact output

Comment: @user3483203 That doesn't answer that.

>>> df['C'].unstack()
B     A     B     C     D
A                        
0  12.0  13.0  14.0   NaN
1  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0

Comment: Please review [ask], and provide a [mcve], showing your current attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `pd.pivot_table()`:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = {'A': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],'B': list('ABCABCD'),'C': range(12, 19)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['A', 'B'])
print(df)
new_df = pd.pivot_table(df,columns=['A'],index=['B'],values=['C'])
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
A     0     1
B
A  12.0  15.0
B  13.0  16.0
C  14.0  17.0
D   NaN  18.0
```